# How to make right to left in jquery listview

Tags: jquery, listview, right-to-left

I want make right to left arabic words in jquery listview. i did try many ways, but no success. i want make `rtl` for arabic words, but `ltr` for latin words inside same `li`. This is what i tried:

I tried to add `dir="RTL"` inside `li` or in `css`, but no success

```
<li>
  <a href="1.htm" rel="external">
    <font style="white-space:normal; font-size: 20pt; font-family: Traditional Arabic;" dir="RTL">Arabic words</font>
    <div>
      <font style="white-space:normal; font-size: 10pt" dir="LTR">LATIN</font>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of  dir="rtl" use style="direction:rtl" or style="direction:ltr".
Hope below changed code will help you. To better understanding I put some extra **dots(..)** after **arabic words** **and LATIN**.

```
<li style="direction:rtl">
    <a href="1.htm" rel="external" >
        <font style="white-space:normal; font-size: 20pt; font-family: Traditional 
        Arabic;">Arabic words...</font>
       <div style="direction:ltr">
           <font style="white-space:normal; font-size: 10pt">LATIN.....</font>
       </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

hope it will help. pardon me if I misunderstood and let me know.